# laravel SAML get NameId value

Tags: laravel, saml

When using the SAML IDP package in Laravel, I am able to see the response but can't get to the value because it is protected:

```
$response = $assertion->getSubject()->getNameID()
```

How do you retrieve the value from the `$response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this function to your `namespace LightSaml\Model\Assertion` class:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
Protected function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}
```

Then you can call the function this way in your Controller:

```
$result = $assertion->getSubject()->getNameID()->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

It needed to be public so I could access it, otherwise I have an error:

```
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}
```